# How to enlarge a partition on an micro-sd card after burning an ubuntu image for an ARM- Board

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, arm, micro-sd

got a problem, that a burned image of ubuntu on a micro-sd card for an arm-Board doesn't fit the whole space on the card and doesn't leave enough space for dist-upgrade. Repartitioning on-the-fly isn't possible as well, so I am a bit confused. How can I enlarge the partition created by burning the image of ubuntu on a micro-sd card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from another drive. For example, you can use the computer, where you burned the image to the card. Use **gparted** to edit the partition table.

If you run Ubuntu live, gparted is available directly from dash (or a the menu in other flavours of Ubuntu). In an installed system, you install gparted with

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

The details how to move and/or grow partitions are described (for a similar case) at the following link,

[GrowIt.pdf](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/GrowIt.pdf)

*Comment:* If you move the head end (left edge in the graphics of gparted), of the partition with the `/boot` directory (often the root partition `/`), the bootloader will not find it, and you have to repair it. This is not difficult, but it is more convenient to keep the position of that head end.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Saved me a lot of time, I would have spend messing around.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help you :-)